# Storm door resists closing

Tags: storm-door

I have a storm door that won't shut properly. In specific it "resists" or bounces back open if you let go when it's about 1 - 1 1/2 inches away from being shut. This means that the self closing mechanism pretty much never works.

I can't identify an obvious culprit for the cause though there are some things I find suspicious. For starters, there's a small gap between the door and the frame at the top of the door on the side without the hinge. There's also some peeling paint near the top hinge, and when you pull the door shut, it does seem like the frame flexes and shifts. But I'm not sure what would be causing the poor fit, since it looks like all the screws are properly tightened.

I tried tightening the screws on the inside of the metal frame, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference. How do I go about figuring out why this door won't shut, and then fix it?

Comment: Sounds like the door got somewhat bent... or the doorway it's mounted to isn't coplanar.

Comment: I suspect the door may not be coplanar. What's the best way to confirm and fix

Comment: If you disconnect the closer, does the door still start resisting closure? If so, then you can start narrowing down exactly what's binding. If not, then the closer (piston-style, right?) might itself be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The air piston on the closer has an adjustment screw on the end of it.

If you tighten it (or turn it clockwise) the door closes slower. Loosening the screw causes it to close faster.

Also, check to make sure the prop clip on the rod is slid back as far as it will go.

Good,luck!